# How much smaller would the industrial revolution been if it had relied on wood/biomass?

Tags: alternate-history, energy

**Terra**: People burned mostly wood for their heating/fuel needs. Then they figured out steam engines. Their fuel needs exploded. They could have kept burning biomass, and they did a little bit, but the problem is one of quantity: there's just more coal around, and that's what allowed the Industrial Revolution to be so big. The steam engine made the world go round for a century or two, then electrification took over (yes I know electricity is steam-made).

**Alternate**: People did indeed figure out steam engines about 1765, and used them, but the Industrial Revolution never scaled to the same level. I do other reasons in the alternate world (the people aren't under the same economic imperatives as drove industrialisation), but I'd be interested in a change of fuel as well.

We all know wood/charcoal/biomass isn't as productive as mining fossil fuels, but my question is quantitatively how much less productive? Could we have a steam era 10% as revolutionary? 5%?

Comment: This didnt work out so well for the inhabitants of Easter Island. :( https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/brv.12556#:~:text=Easter%20Island%20deforestation%20has%20traditionally,precipitated%20its%20own%20cultural%20collapse.

Comment: The question is : would it be a revolution for the people in your world if it is only 10% of what an actual revolution normally is ?

Comment: "archaeological evidence shows that the Rapanui civilization was resilient to deforestation and remained healthy until European contact, which contradicts the occurrence of a cultural collapse" – interesting paper, thanks for posting

Comment: Practically the industrial revolution only happened *because* of coal. Early team engines burned an incredible amount of fuel. And pre-railway transportation costs meant that steam engines had to have their fuel extracted where it was used. This made their only practical application pumping water from deep coal mines. Deep coal mines existed because the major population centers had too many people to rely on wood. (cont.)

Comment: People made persistent improvements on steam engines hoping to sell them to coal mines. But eventually they got efficient enough for use in factories. Without the deep coal mines though, there would have been no reason to persistently improve steam engines fuel effeciency. So they wouldn't have been developed to the point they're economical in factories in the first place without coal.

Comment: @OT-64SKOT go thou forth and turn those two comments into an answer.  Suggest that https://acoup.blog/2022/08/26/collections-why-no-roman-industrial-revolution/ is a good reference to provide the OP for further reading

Comment: The problem with a smaller "industrial revolution" is the reverse of the "network effect". A sufficiently smaller industrial revolution won't have enough people involved to have the "snowball effect" of one invention inspiring the next invention. Instead of a revolution, it might wind up with centuries between inventions. Progress will be very much slower.

Comment: You really think about industrial revolution without abundance of both coal and oil. Oil was available at some sites right on the surface, although refining it was a something not invented until pretty late into the IR, also those regions were pretty uninhabited for a large scale development until electricity or later (Persian Gulf). This requires some serious thinking, and I really feel that energy balance without proper tech for employing wood/biomass as fuel is negative, aka it'll be better to feed horses instead.

Comment: Also there's an interesting thing to check for with biomass: transition from iron to steel required refined coal, as regular coal IIRC could not sustain enough temperature to exile excess CO2 off molten iron to produce steel. This problem would be much worse with biomass, perhaps until the civ would discover some cheap methane production process, which can fuel steel converters, however storage would be quite limited and it's possible that there's a deadlock in tech reqs for methane fuel economy somewhere, so in your alternate world the industrial revolution might not even start.

Comment: I don't think that's right, @Vesper – the inventors of steel used charcoal, not coal; Ctrl+F this for 'coal': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haya_people

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). How much smaller (if at all) is a choice you, the worldbuilder makes. It's not objectively deterministic as we cannot account for the creativity and ingenuity of the world at that time based on an arbitrary limitation. That makes the Q opinion-based, too broad, open-ended, and hypothetical, all prohibited in the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @wokopa, as a follow-up to my closure reason, please note that it's *considerably* easier and always on-topic for you to post a question of the form, "My alternative history has limitation X and I want outcome Y. How can I rationalize Y based on X?" What you're asking is "My alternative history has limitation X, what happens next?" That's always off-topic. We require you to choose where you want your story to go. then we can help you build your world to get there. This reflects the [help/on-topic] requirement that we'll help you build your world, but not tell your story.

Comment: Revolution would be 24.7% of the size

Comment: Economic imperatives did not drive industrialization. Rome had the same economic imperatives but did not industrialize. You might find this article interesting where they try to show the factors that created the industrial revolution. https://www.vox.com/future-perfect/2022/6/1/23138463/how-the-world-became-rich-industrial-revolution-koyama-rubin

Comment: "Rome had the same economic imperatives" – there's no way that's true. Rome did not have the same economics as 1500+ years later. They had free labour (slaves).

Comment: @wokopa Britain had lots of slaves at the start of industrialization. There were slaves working the coal mines and slaves in the overseas colonies. But slaves are not free. Slave labor concentrates wealth in the owners and allows that wealth to be transferred to owners across an ocean. But slaves still require housing and food.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The acoup.blog link someone else has posted in this thread addresses your misconception. ("fell into versions of essentially the same mistake of assuming that Roman social and cultural systems largely mirrored their own")